# Debian openvpn client systemd service

Tags: debian, openvpn, systemd

Just installed openvpn on Debian 9 looking for the right way to enable client at boot:

```
apt install openvpn
```

This won't work:

> Error opening configuration file: /etc/openvpn/myclient

:

```
nano /etc/openvpn/client/myclient.ovpn
systemctl status openvpn-client@myclient
systemctl start openvpn-client@myclient


giu 10 11:23:11 gigi openvpn[15284]: Options error: In [CMD-LINE]:1: Error opening configuration file: myclient.conf
giu 10 11:23:11 gigi openvpn[15284]: Use --help for more information.
giu 10 11:23:11 gigi systemd[1]: openvpn-client@myclient.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
-- Subject: Unit process exited
-- Defined-By: systemd
```

Insteda with the configuration file name will work:

```
nano /etc/openvpn/client/myclient.conf 
systemctl start openvpn-client@myclient
```

but with "-" within the conf name it will fail.

This will work:

```
nano /etc/openvpn/client/myclient.conf
systemctl status openvpn@myclient
systemctl enable openvpn@myclient

● openvpn@myclient.service - OpenVPN tunnel for myclient
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/openvpn-client@.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: inactive (dead)
```

Didn't find any documentation about it to see if should work in one way or the other.

Which way should be preferred openvpn/client/conf or openvpn/conf?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the ".conf" file it is working: /etc/openvpn/client/myclient.conf.
It was the folder path that was wrong!

Comment: Or, you can use just `openvpn@myclient.service` and have `/etc/openvpn/myclient.conf`.